# How to pass value to onclick function

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am doing online shopping Project. From `Add to cart` I want to send multiple ProductID using `onclick` function.

```
$id="";
foreach ($data['product id'] as $key => $value) {
   $id .= $value->Product ID;
}
```

I got all ids in `$id`. How to pass this value in `onclick` function.

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="'.site_url().'checkout/Addcarts/'.$id.'
```

> Error: Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
onclick="activeasheesh('. "'" . $newproject->fld_id . "','" . $newproject->proj_id . "'".')"
```

Answer (score 0):

better to use ajax.
create hyperlink as shown below

```
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="submit_id(<?= $id ?>)">
```

create a jquery function like following

```
    function submit_id(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?= site_url(); ?>checkout/Addcarts/" + id,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(request) {
                console.log(request.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
```